# Silverlight Bind to inverse of boolean property value

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to bind a controls visibility to inverse of boolean property value. I have a property CanDownload, if it is true then I want to hide textbox and vice versa. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This sort of question is asked **so** often and the answers **so** similar I thought its time to have a single answer to all (ok may "most") of the bool to value conversion questions.  I've blogged it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627025931/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx).

The code is quite simple so I'll paste it here too:-

```
public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T FalseValue { get; set; }
    public T TrueValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return FalseValue;
        else
            return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
    }
}
```

Now you can create converter to visibility with a one-liner:-

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Visibility> { }
```

Then for you can create an instance converter in a resource like this:-

```
<local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseVisibility" TrueValue="Collapsed" FalseValue="Visible" />
```

Note the `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` are the swapped around from the more natural order giving you the inverted logic you wanted.  With this in the `Resources` in your `UserControl` or even App.xaml you can now use it to bind to the `CanDownload` property to `TextBox` `Visibility` property:-

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding CanDownload, Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibility}}" />
```

Comment: i am having a strange issue. when i step into the Convert method and hover over targetType it says System.Windows.Visibility but check if(targetType is Visibility) fails. when i do targetType.GetType().ToString() in immediate window it returns System.RuntimeType! i am confused what is happening here

Comment: this is how i am binding <Button Content="Save" Width="100" MaxWidth="100" x:Name="saveButton" Visibility="{Binding CanDownloadVols, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>

Comment: @joblot: The `targetType` parameter is of __type__ `System.Type`, in this case it currently has the __value__ of `System.Windows.Visibility`.  (Read that again carefully this is one those "algebra" moments where nothing else can makes sense until the penny drops.)  When you do `targetType.GetType()` now you've got a `Type` which has the value of a `Type`, in this case `System.RuntimeType` which derives from `System.Type`.  If that last sentence doesn't make sense it because you haven't yet grasped my first sentence. See:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: You could improve the class slightly by utilizing the parameter argument to invert (or not) the returned value.

Answer (score 4):

I use a BoolToVisibilityConverter that allows you to pass "Inverse" as the ConverterParameter to inverse the conversion and show only if the property is false.

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">TargetType must be Visibility</exception>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(value is bool))
            throw new ArgumentException("Source must be of type bool");

        if(targetType != typeof(Visibility))
            throw new ArgumentException("TargetType must be Visibility");

        bool v = (bool) value;

        if(parameter is string && parameter.ToString() == "Inverse")
            v = !v;

        if (v)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ideal since you only need one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this for a recent project using a bool to visibility converter:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType().Equals(typeof(bool)))
        {
            if ((bool)value == true)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
            return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType().Equals(typeof(Visibility)))
        {
            if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Collapsed)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

    #endregion
}
```

I think I could have probably replaced this line:

```
if (value.GetType().Equals(typeof(Visibility)))
```

with something more simple like this:

```
if (value is Visibility)
```

same with the bool GetType, but you get the idea.

Of course, in your converter you can reverse the visility values based on your visibility needs. Hope this helps a little.