# Converter for Byte to Boolean (Checkbox)

Tags: c#, silverlight, checkbox, ivalueconverter

I have am working on Silverlight 4(Existing application) with the following requirement:

**Brief**

1. Should have a search view where there is a checkbox to determine if it should return records according to 1 or 0 flag stored in a certain column
2. The backend part is working fine(retrieving data from a WCF service)
3. The problem I have is converting the Boolean Checkbox value from the front-end to the Byte value(1 or 0) sent to the WCF call that fethes the data

I understand this is where a convertor would work.

I did some of my own searching and found this:

[Silverlight Bind to inverse of boolean property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926451/silverlight-bind-to-inverse-of-boolean-property-value)

This worked brilliantly for DISPLAYING "Yes" for 1 and "No" for 0.

But I am having problems with sending a checkbox True or False value which does the reverse conversion:

i.e It sends to the object as follows:

Checked = 1
Not Checked = 0

**What I have done:**

1. As an example, I have a table with User details as follows:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | USERNAME | ACTIVE |
+----+----------+--------+
|    |          |        |
| 1  | John     | 1      |
|    |          |        |
| 2  | Jane     | 0      |
|    |          |        |
| 3  | Rick     | 1      |
|    |          |        |
| 4  | David    | 0      |
+----+----------+--------+
```

1. I have the following **Convertor** class:

   namespace MyApplication.Silverlight.Converters
   {

   ```
   public class BoolToByteConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public int FalseValue { get; set; }
       public int TrueValue { get; set; }

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           if (value == null)
               return FalseValue;
           else
               return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. My **XAML**

**Namespace declaration**

xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Silverlight.Converters;assembly=MyApplication.Silverlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="140" d:DesignWidth="800">

**Resource declaration**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <converters:BoolToByteConverter x:Key="COneZero" FalseValue="0" TrueValue="1" />
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

**Search Portion**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid x:Name="UserSearchGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <dataInput:Label x:Name="lblName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:" Margin="2" />
                <!--Some Other search fields-->
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkIncludeInActiveUsers"
                          Grid.Row="4"
                          Grid.Column="3"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Content="Include InActive Users"
                          IsChecked="{Binding SearchCriteria.ActiveStatus, Converter={StaticResource COneZero}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Margin="21,4,99,4" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

3. SearchCriteria is an observable object that I use to perform the filtering
4. If there are any namespace issues you identify in the XAML, it is a typo. Please ignore them. My main issue is with the actual convertor.

Thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of your Converter is not correct. You have to swap the implementations of the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods.

The `Convert` method converts a value from your ViewModel to a value for the View and the `ConvertBack` method converts a value from the View to a value of the ViewModel.

So in your case with using the Converter in the Binding of the `IsChecked`-Property of the CheckBox the `Convert` method gets a Byte value and converts is to a Boolean, while the `ConvertBack` method gets a Boolean and converts it to a Byte.

```
public class BoolToByteConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        else
            return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? System.Convert.ToByte(value) : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jehof,

Sorry for the late reply. That did it. Marking as answer. Edit: Added full qualification of the system type conversion calls(prefixed with "System.") as it confuses the compiler with the internal Convert method...and throws "Namespace.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context"